# API POST Request: empty values vs. null values vs. removed values

Tags: angular, rest, api, post

I'm using MongoDB and Node.js for my *backend API* and Angular for my *frontend*.

I have two data models in Angular, one representing the data expected from user input and the other representing the data expected by the API in my back end.

```
class DataForm {
  authorName: string;
  wordEnglish: string;
  wordExpanded?: string;
  definition: string;
  linkAuthoritative?: string;
  linkWikipedia?: string;
  linkYoutube?: string;
}

export class EnglishTermRequest {
  constructor() {
  this.languageCode = 'en';
  }
  wordEnglish: string;
  wordNonEnglish: string;
  wordExpanded: string;
  languageCode: string;
  image: string;
  imageType: string;
  audio: string;
  audioType: string;
  linkAuthoritative: string;
  linkWikipedia: string;
  linkYouTube: string;
  authorName: string;
  fieldOfStudy: string;
  helpYes: number;
  helpNo: number;
  definitions: [DefinitionRequest];
}
```

The reason why I have two separate models is so that I can easily modify the input data before storing them in a model that the API expects.

The question I have is what do I do with empty or null values from the user?
For example, if the user does not provide an input for one of the properties, right now my model is set up that the properties don't exist in the object.

```
dataForm = {
authorName : "Bob",
wordEnglish: "Hello",
definition: "Random definition aasdfjkad"
}
```

If I store this inside the EnglishTermRequest model to make a POST request, this model will have missing properties for *wordExpanded*, *linkAuthoritative*, etc.

Is this okay or should I make the values null or empty strings(or whatever default value of the type)?
Should my MongoDB database hold all properties that it expects for each model or can it have missing properties?

Comment: So long as your MongoDB fields aren't "mandatory" then it's okay to leave them null. Just to make sure to sanitize your code so that returned null values don't break anything. See following post for schema validation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

Comment: @Dexirian if I send a JSON object with missing properties to the backend, should the backend be responsible for populating the empty properties with null values? Or should the frontend check for any missing properties in the JSON object and fill them will null values?

Comment: Probably on the front-end, as to have the least amount of steps to have a full query